# Pattern for Recursive Construction

Tags: induction, invariance

Suppose I have this recursive definition of binary strings. Let $K$ be set of binary strings. The empty string $""$ and $1$ are in $K$. If $k$ is a string in $K$, then so is $0k$, $k0$. And if $k$ is a string in $K$, then so is $k01$.

I'm trying to find a property and then prove with structural induction that is satisfied by all the strings in K and I cannot seem to find the invariant, the property that does not change as the strings in K gets more complicated. I have listed some of the strings in K below:

Length 0: $""$

Length 1:  $0,1$

Length 2: $00, 01, 10$

Length 3: $000, 001, 010, 100, 101$

Length 4: $0000, 0001, 0010, 0100, 1000, 0101, 1010, 1001$

Can anyone see a pattern?

Comment: The pattern $1,2,3,5,8,\dots$ may be familiar.

Comment: Yes, but I need a property that describes each particular string so maybe Ross Millikan may be right.

Comment: He is. I was giving information in case you need to find the **number** of patterns of length $n$. One gets essentially the Fibonacci numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me all strings that do not have two $1$'s together.

Comment: But how can you use this property for a structural induction proof. The structural induction proofs I have read so far involve the comparison of different qualities of one object

Comment: I don't know structural induction, but I can see how to generate any string matching my rule and don't see any way to get two $1$'s together.